# jQuery height() returns approximately half of the real height value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

*Update at the end!*

I've container panel which has set of comments. Each comment has different length, so container's height should be dynamic, this can be done by `height:auto`. To be able to enter a new comment user should click a button and an input text will be rendered under the comment panel. So I've written a js function which gets the height of the panel and sets it as input text's position top value which is:

```
var commentPanelStr = 'dataTableFormHM' + ':dataTableHM:' + rowIndex + ':commentPanel';
var commentPanel = $(document.getElementById(commentPanelStr));
commentPanel.css({
    "height":"auto",
    "top":commentPanelTopValue
});

var commentInputPanelStr = 'dataTableFormHM' + ':dataTableHM:' + rowIndex + ':commentInputPanel';
var commentInputPanel = $(document.getElementById(commentInputPanelStr));

var y = parseInt(commentPanel.height())+commentPanelTopValue;
commentInputPanel.css("top", y);
```

Problem about this function is; `commentPanel.height()` returns approximately half of the real height value. Below picture shows how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

But it's looking like:

[image]

I've tried to change function header to `$(window).load()` instead  `$(document).ready()`. Also `outerHeight() $(elem).css('height');$(elem)[0].height; $(elem)[0].innerHeight; $(elem)[0].clientHeight;` functions returns wrong values.

Also jQuery position() function inserts inputText into middle of the comment Panel which is the approximately half of the comment panel with below code:

```
commentInputPanel.position({my:"bottom",at:"bottom",of:commentPanel});
```

I think jQuery functions can not get the exact value of `height:auto` but the question is why?

Related xhtml code:

```
<p:panel id="commentPanel" style="width:353px; height:34px;position:absolute;left:370px;top:149px;"
                         styleClass="statusComment">
                    <ui:param name="max" value="#{Status.numOfCommentsShown}"/>
                    <ui:repeat var="Comment" value="#{Status.commentListOfStatus}" varStatus="statusVar">
                        <ui:fragment rendered="#{statusVar.index lt max}">
                            <li>
                                <div class="wrapper" id="wrapperDiv" style="word-wrap: break-word;width: 335px;">
                                    <h:link value="#{Comment.commentAuthorName}: " id="goToProfileWithAuthorName"
                                            outcome="/profile.xhtml" type="submit"
                                            style="text-decoration:none;font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;font-size: 11px;color: rgb(120,120,159);">
                                        <f:param name="userId" value="#{Comment.comauthorId}"/>
                                    </h:link>

                                    <h:outputText id="commentText" value="#{Comment.commentText}"
                                                  style="font-family:arial;font-size: 11px;color: rgb(77,77,103);"></h:outputText>
                                    <br/>
                                    <abbr class="timeago" title="#{Comment.commentDate}"
                                          style="color: #778899;font-size: 10px;">
                                    </abbr>
                                    <p:commandLink styleClass="deleteCommentButton" style="display:none;">
                                        <p:graphicImage value="/images/smallCancel.png" alt="delete"
                                                        style="outline: none; border:none"/>
                                    </p:commandLink>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ui:fragment>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:panel>
```

Thanks for helping.

**Update!**

I think I found the reason! As it can be seen in the xhtml, I have br tag and a commandlink with an Image. When I delete that br tag image and timeago is written right after the comment in the same line and in this case height() is calculated correctly.

But whenever I will use a `<br/>` or `<p/>` which means there is a new line, `height()` functions are corrupted. But I have no idea how to fix?

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Are you open to leveraging jQuery UI's Position utility? http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: @Ejay Ok I sent it but I'm using JSF so maybe generated HTML can be more helpful. Also ther is nothing about CSS float.

Comment: @DavidTansey so you suggesting me to insert inputText with jQueryUI's position utility?

Comment: @DavidTansey so weird behaviour, `commentInputPanel.position({my:"bottom",at:"bottom",of:commentPanel});` inserts inputText to half of the commentPanel sth. corrupts these functions.

Comment: Have you tried offsetHeight?

Comment: @PranitG offsetHeight gives 300px when it's 350px's. I really don't understand why, sth. must be triggering this.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery.outerHeight(true) ? http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Comment: Yes I've tried. Problem is not about including/excluding margins or padding values that's why js functions are giving wrong values. Problem is about generated html code which has br and li tags those are confusing js func. somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching about `<br/>` tag found out it has NO height at all. It just forcibly ends the line, that's all. That's why all js functions are calculating height wrong because they don't care br tag.

It was a huge and a bit funny mistake styling with `<br/>` tag. I was checking ajax callback parameters, almost tried all possibilities to get the correct height via javascript but not worked. In the end, br tag similing me and tries to teach something:

It is not so important how much you deep at using prepared libraries as long as you don't know basics well!

And one more thing, root cause can be `<li/>` tag as well, if you have 2 lines make sure you are having 2 `<li/>` tags